# Can a homebrew classes starting hit points be higher than it's hit dice?

Tags: dnd-5e, homebrew, hit-points, hit-dice

So I was wonder if I could make a class that's starting hit points were higher than it's hit dice?

> **Hit points**
>
> **Hit Dice:** 1d10 per ______ level
>
> **Hit Points** **at 1st level:** 12 + your Constitution modifier

Would this be allowed or would its starting hit points have to be 10 to be equal to it's hit dice?

Comment: Can you give some explanation for why you want to do this?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov the question was more about if there was any rules saying "No" this isn't allowed.

Comment: "Would this be allowed" by whom?

Comment: @Smart_TJ Please don't answer in comments. [We try not to do that here.](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6533)

Comment: I've rolled back your question to the original. The edit seems to be asking a new question and you'd be better served posting that separately (but please take a look at seeing if you actually need to ask it.)

Comment: @MikeZ. Hop in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/trpg-general-chat) and we can workshop a new question with you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Homebrew doesn't have rules

Even if every single class that already exists follows an exact pattern that's never been broken, you don't have to do the same thing.

There just aren't any rules for this, you can make whatever you want, however fantastical, overpowered, or complicated as you like. It may differ from how the system usually works, and what you should be doing then is *justifying that choice*.

If you're going to give a class a meager *two* additional hit points, I would hope there is a good reason. It's a small change and one people are likely not to even notice given the way every single other class is structured. If this is a vitally important aspect of the homebrew, it should be emphasized in the text and the change should be made clear.

In all honesty, I see this type of change adding confusion and for very little gain (+2 HP is very little). That doesn't mean you can't do it anyway, you can do *anything* you want, but you should have justifications for when you depart from the usual format of the system.

Answer (score 4):

#### There are no rules for homebrew. That's the point. But it is up to the DM to permit it.

There is some guidance in the *Dungeon Master's Guide* (p. 287-289) for modifying and creating class features, and this guidance doesn't have anything like what you describe. But that's okay. The whole point of homebrew is to create something that doesn't exist.

That said, you will have to ask your DM before using any homebrew features at the table.